# What is the purpose of trophy pushing?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Why do people in Clash of Clans trophy push? It really has no point, and it has me confused why anyone would want to 'town hall snipe' in order to get to a higher league. Any insight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People in Clash of Clans trophy push for a few reasons:

- Achieve a personal record by seeing how high they can get (solo or with a clan)
- Earn a gem bonus when they reach Crystal, Master, and Champion
- [Win bonus](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Trophy_Leagues) can make it worth it on bases to town hall snipe:
  [image]

Comment: FYI with the latest update, the win bonus has gone up for every league I think.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer, clans sometimes push all at once to make themselves look nice, and then try to recruit players.